# How to get the names of the namespaces loaded at the beginning

Tags: c#, namespaces

How to get the names of the namespaces loaded at the beginning of a C# file? For example, get the six namespace names below.

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MyNM
{
    class MyClass{}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This returns all the assemblies references by the executed assembly.

Still, this will NOT return only the namespaces used within a specific file - which is impossible at runtime.

```
var asms = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies();

foreach (var referencedAssembly in asms)
{
    Console.WriteLine(referencedAssembly.Name);
}
```

Although, you can, technically, if you know the name of the file which contains your current code, simply read the file at runtime and extract the "using's".

**EDIT**

The way to do this would be:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetUsings()
{
    // Gets the file name of the caller
    var fileName = new StackTrace(true).GetFrame(1).GetFileName();

    // Get the "using" lines and extract and full namespace
    return File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
               .Select(line => Regex.Match(line, "^\\s*using ([^;]*)"))
               .Where(match => match.Success)
               .Select(match => match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: I have tried Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies(), but it missed some namespaces if in the context, classes in these namespaces are not used at all. However, in my problem, I want to micmic the same coding environment.

Comment: @KenS I've implemented a method to get the actual `using`s from the current file. See edit! :)

Comment: I just noticed. The matching string looks amazing to me. :) I will try this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> How to get the names of the namespaces loaded at the beginning of a C# file? For example, get the six namespace names below.

You can't, other than parsing the file yourself (or using something like the Roslyn CTP to parse a C# file).

Namespaces aren't "loaded" - they are only used by the compile, at compile time, to resolve the appropriate type names.

You can use [Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies.aspx) to get the assemblies referenced by your *assembly* (ie: project), but this is an assembly wide set of references, and distinctly different than the namespace using directives included in a specific *file*.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. It make sense. In my problem, I want to mimic the same coding enviroment, hmmm, with more namespaces loaded, no less. So probably I would like to do this way: (1) Get all file in the assembly directory of the current app, (2) Get all the assemblies (3) Get all the namespaces in these assemblies.  It may not exactly the same, but any codes executable in current app should be executable in the mimicing one.

Comment: @KenS That's actually not possible without parsing the file - you can have using alias directives in the original file that give namespaces aliases, which would cause code (even with all namespaces setup) to not run.  Adding all namespaces could also cause naming conflicts, which introduces its own problems.

Comment: @ReedCopsey He can easily check for naming conflicts and handle them with aliasing, for example: `using Timer2 = System.Threading.Timer;`

Comment: @YoryeNathan There's no way to know which "Timer" would be the appropriate one to alias, though, to make the original source work.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Change all `Timer` in a file to `Timer2` and change `using System.Threading.Timer` to `using Timer2 = System.Threading.Timer`. This will not collide with other `Timer`s in different namespaces from different files.

Comment: @YoryeNathan If all you have is the references, and a file uses "Timer", you have no way to know if it's System.Threading.Timer or System.Timers.Timer or System.Windows.Forms.Timer or some other timer, as they can ALL be referenced at once...

Comment: @ReedCopsey They can all be references at once, but they will have different usages within the file, so the functionality won't be broken.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the file to derive the Syntax elements. As mentioned above, you can use System.Reflections for external references or you can use the new [Roslyn compiler service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx) as below

```
string codeSnippet = @"using System;
using System.CodeDom;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MyNM
{
    class MyClass{}
}";
            //APPROACH:
            //Get using statements in the code snippet from the syntax tree
            //find qualified name(eg:System.Text..) in the using directive 

            SyntaxTree tree = SyntaxTree.ParseCompilationUnit(codeSnippet);
            SyntaxNode root = tree.GetRoot();
            IEnumerable<UsingDirectiveSyntax> usingDirectives = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<UsingDirectiveSyntax>();
            foreach(UsingDirectiveSyntax usingDirective in usingDirectives){
                NameSyntax ns = usingDirective.Name;
                Console.WriteLine(ns.GetText());
            }
```

NOTE: The code uses older version of Roslyn API. It may break in future as Roslyn is still a CTP.